# Model not working in Magento 1.5.0 from tutorial about Magento's Model and ORM basics

Tags: orm, magento, model, entity-attribute-value

I've been following this tutorial about Magento's Model and ORM basics too. I'm using Magento Version 1.5.0, and when i came across on testing the model if it works specially in printing the object in this code, all i get is a blank white page.

```
public function testModelAction() {
    $blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
    echo get_class($blogpost);
}
```

I went to see the system log and i get these errors

```
2011-02-16T04:18:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Alanstormdotcom\Weblog\Model\Blogpost.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94

2011-02-16T04:18:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Alanstormdotcom\Weblog\Model\Blogpost.php' for inclusion (include_path='E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local;E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\community;E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core;E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib;.;E:\xampp\php\PEAR') in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94

2011-02-16T04:18:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Alanstormdotcom\Weblog\controllers\IndexController.php on line 6
```

Hope you can help me in resolving this problem..

Thank you..

Comment: Please also post relevant parts of your `config.xml` file and the `Alanstormdotcom\Weblog\Model\Blogpost.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

What sort of bum writes a tutorial that doesn't work?!

Take a look at your error message

```
2011-02-16T04:18:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Alanstormdotcom\Weblog\Model\Blogpost.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94
```

Magento is telling you it can't find your model file.  Have you created the model named Blogpost.php?  Is it in the right folder?  It should be at

```
app\code\local\Alanstormdotcom\Weblog\Model\Blogpost.php
```

If Magento can't find it, that means it's not there.  If it is there, than means someone's monkeied with your include path.

Comment: its absolutely there. i created the file as told in the tutorial but i still got the error..

Comment: i was really thinking maybe because i'm using the new version 1.5.0 i will try install lower version and see what happen, i'll update you..

Comment: Perhaps a file permission problem then?

Comment: Thank you Alan, you are right, its my blogpost.php it turned out Blogpost.php.php, wrong filename..i monkeied it..really sorry..thank you all for the time.. :)

Comment: No worries, all the new stuff in Magento tends to make you miss the easy things.

Answer (score 0):

this the Alanstormdotcom\Weblog\Model\Blogspot.php

```
class Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('weblog/blogpost');
    }   
}
```

this is the config.xml

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Alanstormdotcom_Weblog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Alanstormdotcom_Weblog>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <weblog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog</module>
                    <frontName>weblog</frontName>
                </args>
            </weblog>
        </routers> 
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <weblog>
                <class>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </weblog>
        </models>
    </global>   
</config>
```

Comment: In future use the Code Sample button to properly indent your code, then tags will show as you expect.